# Can I shoot in 16:9 then change it to 4:3?

Tags: framerate, aspect

I'm trying to get the old film look with Canon 600D, so I will be shooting in 640*480 25 fps. But what if I shoot in 16:9 at 24 fps, will I be able to get the same 4:3 after editing? (The reason I'm asking this is films are 24 fps, 600D doesn't have 4:3 at 24 fps)

Comment: If you are going for an old film look don't lower the resolution, thats not getting you any closer to the look and limits your possibilities in post.
The only good reason to shoot at a lower resolution is to save storage space. You can always downscale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can set your project up so that it will output a 4:3 video. However, keep in mind that there are only two ways to achieve this:

- Nr. 1 You crop the video, which means you will lose stripes of the video at both the left and the right side.

Here's an example:

[image]

- Nr. 2: You resize the 16:9 input video so that it fits in the 4:3 output video. I wouldn't recommend this though, since the video and everything in it will be deformed, which looks completely aweful.

So if this is your input:

[image]

It will result in this output:

[image]

Both options result in a quality / information loss. How about shooting in 4:3 at a higher framerate? You could easily lower the framerate in editing to achieve your desired effect ...

Comment: I'm thinking about the number 1. Is the result of that same as if I shoot in 4:3 ?

Comment: The resulting video will have an 4:3 aspect ratio, yes. It will most likely look like you shot your video in 4:3. However, while filming, you'll have to remember that you will lose said stripes at both sides, so you can't have e.g. a person stand in the very side of the 16:9 video, since this person will figuratively be cut in half during editing.

Comment: I guess I will have to use 4:3 at 25 fps.

Comment: @CatwithaFez Just so you know, Magic Lantern allows  you to film with crop marks so that you can film in 16:9 with a 4:3 crop mark so you can see what will be cut in post.

Answer (score 0):

When you shoot 4:3 on a DSLR, it simply crops off the edges for you at the time of filming so that you can save disk space by not capturing video that you are going to throw away.  There is no reason not to shoot in 16:9 and then crop in post.

Shooting in 16:9 at the correct frame rate is the highest possible quality for your situation.  Adjusting frame rate in post results in a loss of quality if it isn't an exact multiple (and even then it can be argued it does due to the shutter speed used).  The one thing you have to keep in mind when shooting is where the edges will be when cropped though.  I recommend using the center.  You can either measure it out and place board tape on the screen (like masking tape, but less residue) or you can use something like Magic Lantern to overlay guidelines for you to use while shooting.

Comment: One more thing: Do you recommend using 480p for the old film look or just use 108p at 24fps then crop it 4:3 ?

Comment: @CatwithaFez - depends if you are looking for the old film look or the old TV look.  For the old film look, the quality was actually pretty high, but the color mapping was different.  For video, both the resolution and color mapping were different as was the interlacing.  If you want it to have an older look, it is going to need more than just the 4:3 and 480 scan line resolution applied to it, but that's really another question entirely.